# bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Tags: 18.04, bash, repository, sh, source

I am trying to install **fpylll** from a [repository](https://github.com/fplll/fpylll/) on **Ubuntu 18.04**
The fpylll instruction in [README.rst](https://github.com/fplll/fpylll/blob/master/README.rst) says that after Automatic install you should do

```
$ source ./activate
```

but I get a notification:

```
/ bin / sh: 1: source: not found
```

why it happens? I thought the **source** is in **bash** by eliciting? How to solve this problem?

Comment: @mook765
Help what should I do? What exactly needs to be changed?

Comment: is there a reason why not use `sudo apt install python-fpylll`

Answer (score 2):

please replace "source ./activate" with ". ./activate"

see: [Bourne shell builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_002e)

good luck.

Comment: After I ran the command:
`PYTHON = python3 ./bootstrap.sh` I get a notification: `Installed /content/fpylll/fpylll-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fpylll-0.5.6-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for fpylll==0.5.6
Finished processing dependencies for fpylll==0.5.6
Don't forget to activate environment each time: `

Comment: Then, as you wrote, I ran the command: `./activate`  As a result, nothing was displayed in the terminal. Then I ran my script and got notifications that the module is missing:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 35, in <module>
    from fpylll import LLL, BKZ, IntegerMatrix
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpylll'`

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04 but the script needs to be run on Python3. From the [documentation] (https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/python3-fpylll_0.5.2+ds1-3_amd64.deb.html), this only works on Ubuntu 21.04.
Then I decided to install fpylll via repositories. But don’t know what the problem is?

Comment: hi @DewDebra. Activate only sets enviroment variables to point to the Libs and bootstrap.sh is a shell script. Take a look at https://github.com/fplll/fpylll/blob/master/bootstrap.sh on lines 33-39 and 50-55. Those lines set enviroment variables.

Comment: So you need to set your enviroment correctly to be able to run it. what do you get with "env" and "env python" commands.